# Macro to Copy or Create Macros

Tags: vba, excel, button

I've got a problem where I want some buttons to run a macro, but it needs to work across hundreds of excel files that I'll be sending out. So it worked great to put the macros for the buttons into the Personal file, but if I email the files out, the link to my personal file is of course lost.

I can copy the personal module to each workbook and have the buttons, when created, reference ActiveSheet, but copying the module to every book will be insanely tedious.

Is there a macro I could run that would automatically copy the module when creating the buttons, or some other solution?

Thanks!

Comment: [Working in the VBE](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx) will be very useful to you.